# character splits in half when moving leg

Tags: rigging, rigify

I'm new to Blender and playing around a little bit, trying to make a decent enough character that can walk and what not. My problem is, so far all of my rigs seem to split in half when I move the leg. The lower torso moves with the leg and the belly pretty much gets cut open up to the belly button.

[image]

When I modeled the character I applied a mirror modifier. Could that be the reason? If so, what did I do wrong?

Is there any way to fix this without having to start over?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem you should had the "clipping" option checked in the mirror modifier. Now simply go to rest pose (select all bones, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>), then in edit mode select all and remove doubles, or manually join (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>) the unconnected vertices, which probably are one on top of the other.